# c# form post runs first or the javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

if on submit button of a web form , a java-script function is attached then what will happen first? the form will posted first OR the java-script function runs first?

Answer (score 2):

The javascript is client-side, it means it will be executed before the POST because after this everything is happenning server-side, then in your case with the C#.

Comment: are you sure for that?

Comment: Yes. If your javascript is not running check your event triggered.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, on submit is run first if there is a javascript function attached, and you could cancel the form submitting inside that function by using `return false;` or `event.preventDefault` (due to invalid form data for example).

```
form.onsubmit = function(event){
   //if data is not valid
   return false;
}
```